# Window Navigation using <Window> tag only

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Is it possible to go to next window or go back to a window using just `<window>` tag. I searched through internet and didn't find it anywhere. Whenever navigation is needed, I found `<Window.Navigation>` is in use. But using but this browser like tab on top I want  window to navigate when I click m Ok or cancel button on my `<Window>`.

P.S. I am new to WPF. So I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If NavigationWindow would work for you except for the navigation tab on top, the simplest thing to do is set ShowsNavigationUI=false.  Alternatively (a bigger hammer, but more flexible) you can replace the Template on your window and that will also remove it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to navigate by using the Window class, but it depends what you want to achieve. You can assign your newly created Windows to the applications MainWindow.

EDIT: I did some tests: Other than the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx) states you cannot assign a new Window to the MainWindow property like this:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = new MyWindow(); // does not work!
```

The main window is special, when it is closed the application will normally be closed.

However it might be easier to use the  class as it has a NavigationService property which makes navigation a easier. You finde some documentation under http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx